# Four 4s to make a 4

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Shown below is an equation with four 4s on the LHS and a 4 on the RHS with 4 rectangular boxes and 3 ovals.

Make this equation correct by replacing the rectangular boxes by 4 separate single items without using the digits 0 to 9 or any numbers (including fractions) formed with those digits and replacing the Ovals with the math operators + - * or / only.

[image]

Comment: Are the operators applied left-to-right or in normal precedence order? (I have an answer that relies on left-to-right calculation.)

Comment: And can I leave some of the postfix items empty?

Comment: 4 distinctly separete things (no empty space) in the rectangles and any 3 math operators from the list in any order in the ovals. As long as the math adds up.

Comment: Query 1 :: Should the ovals be Distinct with each other AND with the rectangles ? Query 2 :: "As long as the math adds up" : Can we use "!" in the last rectangle to get "!=4", meaning "not equal", to get a "true inequality" ?

Comment: Yes @Prem. Not equal to is not in the spirit of this puzzle.

Comment: Yes, I know != is not allowed, but the wording was ambiguous, hence clarifying. Ok, with the ovals being Distinct with each other AND with the rectangles, I guess the second answer by user "loopy walt" is invalid , because it uses "-" 4 times.

Comment: Trying to use equality $|4^i|=1$ but no success yet.

Comment: Without defining the character set, I think these types of problems become very open ended. Sorry, I vote close. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @Amoz , I agree. The answer by user "Tom" uses ratios to get 2+2=4, with no use of the given 4s in the LHS of the Puzzle; replacing the LHS 4s with 5s (or 8s) will still result in 2+2=4; while that answer is not wrong, it only shows that the Puzzle is very general and openended.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the sometimes promoted

> [tau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_(angle)#Proposals_for_a_single_letter_to_represent_2%CF%80) = 2pi, and also the symbols d, r for the diameter and radius of a circle

to provide the solution

> $4\tau / 4\pi + 4d / 4r= 4$

Comment: That works. My answer is a lot more complicated. :)

Comment: One Issue with this solution is that, while PI & TAU are "standard", D & R are not. In case, non-standard "variables" are allowed, we might as well use X & Y, claiming that Y=2X.

Answer (score 2):

With units of time:

> `4--4h-4d/4!` where `h` and `d` denote hours and days and `!` is the factorial.

or similar without any units:

> `4!-4--4(-4)` with juxtaposition read as multiplication.

Normal precedence rules apply (multiplication/division before addition/subtraction).